# How to mathematically formalize this type of Array search

Tags: arrays, math, search

I want so search an Array with the pattern you can see in the picture. We start at a given point (x,y) which is marked in red and go on as shown in the picture:

[image]

My approach until now was to use a self-made list which looks like this (for example in python code):

```
list = [ [(0,0)], [(1,0),(0,1),(-1,0),(0,-1)], [(1,1),(-1,-1),(1,-1),(-1,1)], ... ]
          (RED)           (ORANGE)                   (CYAN)                    (...)
```

But obviously this is not a very smart solution and its not scalable, so I have to know the size of  my array.
Does anyone have an idea if there is a mathematical algorithm behind this type of search?

Comment: What do you mean by "mathematical algorithm"? Will Python code suffice? Or do you want a mathematical equation / function?

Comment: Looks almost like searching out from the center by radius 0, then by radius 1, ... and so on.

Comment: @ rory daulton yes python code would suffice. With mathematical i meant a alorithmen that does't work with an handmade list like i made it.

Comment: @James K Polk Yes your right. The whole use of this ist to find the nearest neighbor of a point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this actually is what you are looking for, but surely there is an algorithm for generating this list dynamically, given that you know the size of your *bidimensional* array at runtime.

This is a quick sketch in Java (I used Point as a wrapper for pair of integers, you can use another class as long as its `equals` and `hashCode` have the obvious implementation referring to both members)

```
    int max = 5; // replace with the actual size of your matrix
    for (int i = 0; i <= max; i++) {
        // I use a set to skip ugly checks for duplicates in first iterations
        Set<Point2D> coll = new HashSet<>();

        // first loop takes care of the sides of your squares (even numbers in your image)
        for (int x = -i + 1; x < i; x++) {
            coll.add(new Point(i, x));
            coll.add(new Point(-i, x));
            coll.add(new Point(x, i));
            coll.add(new Point(x, -i));
        }
        System.out.println("STEP = " + (2 * i));
        System.out.println((coll));

        // second loop takes care of the vertices of your squares (odd numbers in your image)
        coll = new HashSet<>();
        coll.add(new Point(i, i));
        coll.add(new Point(-i, i));
        coll.add(new Point(i, -i));
        coll.add(new Point(-i, -i));
        System.out.println("STEP = " + (2 * i + 1));
        System.out.println((coll));
    }
```

The snippet just prints the collection of points in console, you can add them to a list or use them directly.

Comment: tkanks a lot. Actually i dont want the list. I just want to search in a array in this order. But i think that should do it. Thank you :)